# Difference between -D and -d environment variables in Java

Tags: java, environment-variables, uppercase, lowercase

I understood how environment variables works in Java, setting -DVariable and getting with System.getProperty("Variable"). But i've seen sometimes examples with "-d" variable using lowercase, and I wonder what's the difference between that? I found no answer googling.. Thanks in advance

Comment: The `-d` options (e.g `-da` or `-d32`) are completely different. Please give some examples of where you've seen them.

Comment: I've read about this in this topic: http://www.coderanch.com/t/178539/java-SCJA/certification/java-command-line-option-good and I found no answers about -d variable (sorry for my english)

Comment: @Develop22 - I think that that example is just misleading.

Comment: @Develop22: Well that topic says that they're different... where have you seen examples of them being treated as being the same?

Comment: I just remember seeing sometime some variable using -d and reading this topic I wondered about the difference, considering that both are asked in OCJP exam and finding no info in google about -d

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`java -help` prints:

-D=
              set a system property

if invoked with -d it prints the error messages:

```
Unrecognized option: -d
```

another option starting with d:

-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
(This cannot be used to set variables).